# Python Import Error: I am getting error when importing function from package. Import error on test.py when performing mymath.multiply()

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

**This is my Directory Structure:**

```
test.py
mymath/
    __init__.py
    mymath.py
```

**test.py**

```py
import mymath
mymath.multiply()
```

**__init__.py**

```py
from mymath
import multiply
```

**mymath.py**

```py
def multiply():
```

When I run:

```
python3 test.py
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mymath
  File "/home/kcb/python-scripts/mymath/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mymath import multiply
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiply'
```

Comment: What is error post your error. And please format your question better.

Comment: Hope you can see it better now.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: In the directory structure diagram, what is the purpose of the `|` symbol between `test.py` and `mymath/`?  If it's meant to indicate that those two things are siblings, then it's inconsistent, as you don't have one between `__init__.py` and `mymath.py`.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Sorry for the confustion. Just trying to indicate they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `python myscript.py`, the current working directory directory is added to your module search path, and thus any modules in that directory are importable.

However, when `mymath/__init__.py` tries to do `from mymath import multiply`, it can't find `mymath.py`, because `mymath/` is not in your module search path.

The best solution is to change `mymath/__init__.py` to use a different import statement:

```
from .mymath import multiply
```

This means "import `multiply` from a module named `mymath` *in the same directory as this module*."